# Software sources is not opening

Tags: apt, package-management, python, software-center

Here is the terminal output.

```
software-properties-gtk 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 363, in get_name_owner
    's', (bus_name,), **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 653, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 161, in __init__
    proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 243, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 280, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 653, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties: Permission denied
```

Comment: what version of Ubuntu? If 19.04 it just expired. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.

Comment: My guess is you're not using the correct version of python3 for your release; but you didn't provide OS/release details. Please do, and provide the output of `python3 -V`

Comment: It’s a fresh install of Ubuntu recovered some data with rsync. I’ll Check that in the am I was thinking it was a permission issue or user related. I will explain tomorrow with with more detail of what precipitated it.

Comment: Python 3.7.5 is the output.

Comment: So i was having issues with the workspace manager nolonger working so i used rsync to move my Applications and user folder and opt folder and an Application folder i gereranted for appimages. formatted and reinstalled Budgie newest version same version as before then i recovered with rsync and used chown on the home folder to assign all the files to me again everything is working properly minus this one App i dont use it as i use the terminal but is is super irritating that  i cant figure out why it fails to open and work.

Comment: I resolved the issue with a big hammer i reinstalled and used different arguments and did the home dir /opt and /etc/apt sources and sources.d among a few other locations and i got a 100 percent working distro again i appreciate your help it has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

The source got moved to the pop os source accidentally needed to revert to the old source and reinstall the setting gtk

Comment: Please explain how this answers the OPs question and provide actual steps required to fix the issue. Thanks.